# addEventListener on loaded html file

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

i'm trying to create multiple `addEventListener`'s on Microsoft visual studio 2015 - language: javascript + html.

## 1 Load another HTML file inside content div

```
WinJS.UI.Fragments.renderCopy(resourcesDir + '/' + data + '.html', output)
```

## 2 in that html file there are 30 items that I want to react on onclick.

now when I try to (see comment):

```
WinJS.UI.Fragments.renderCopy(resourcesDir + '/' + data + '.html', output)
         .done(
            function () {
                    WinJS.UI.Animation.exitContent(output, null).done(function () {
                    return WinJS.UI.Animation.enterContent(output, null);
                });
                if (data == 'alphabet') {
                   // ####### IF i try to addEventListener HERE it only works for first item..
                }
            },
            function (error) {

            }
        );
```

How is it possible to create loop for 30 times that would add Event Listener?
or is there any other way to create onclick option?  - because CONTENT wont work..

Thank you!

Comment: If your question is about `addEventListener`, at least show it to us... Is this the kind of loop you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/r2e35rxz/

Comment: @blex oh, thank you, it worked.